# OCI does not appear in php info

Tags: php, unix, xampp, redhat, oci8

OS: RHEL 7.8

```
/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client
[root@rb-opdev-01 client]# php --version
PHP 7.4.8 (cli) (built: Jul  9 2020 08:57:23) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

PHP(XAMPP) log:

```
[23-Jul-2020 07:52:33 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/login.php:20
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/login.php on line 20
```

I can't see OCI in phpinfo page but oci8 is installed.

```
[23-Jul-2020 07:52:33 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/login.php:20
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/login.php on line 20
[root@rb-opdev-01 client]# php -i
phpinfo()
PHP Version => 7.4.8

System => Linux rb-opdev-01.mtg.local 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 18 16:39:12 EST 2020 x86_64
Build Date => Jul  9 2020 08:57:23
Build System => Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8 (Maipo)
Build Provider => Remi Collet
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/20-bz2.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-sodium.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-xml.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php.d/20-xsl.ini,
/etc/php.d/30-xmlreader.ini

PHP API => 20190902
PHP Extension => 20190902
Zend Extension => 320190902
Zend Extension Build => API320190902,NTS
PHP Extension Build => API20190902,NTS
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => disabled
Zend Signal Handling => enabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
Zend Multibyte Support => disabled
IPv6 Support => enabled
DTrace Support => available, disabled

Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, compress.bzip2, phar
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp, unix, udg, ssl, sslv3, tls, tlsv1.0, tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2
Registered Stream Filters => zlib.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, dechunk, bzip2.*, convert.iconv.*

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies


 _______________________________________________________________________


Configuration

bz2

BZip2 Support => Enabled
Stream Wrapper support => compress.bzip2://
Stream Filter support => bzip2.decompress, bzip2.compress
BZip2 Version => 1.0.6, 6-Sept-2010

calendar

Calendar support => enabled

Core

PHP Version => 7.4.8

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => UTF-8 => UTF-8
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => Off => Off
display_startup_errors => Off => Off
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => Off => Off
enable_post_data_reading => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 22527 => 22527
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => /usr/lib64/php/modules => /usr/lib64/php/modules
file_uploads => On => On
hard_timeout => 2 => 2
highlight.comment => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font> => <font style="color: #FF8000">#FF8000</font>
highlight.default => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font> => <font style="color: #0000BB">#0000BB</font>
highlight.html => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font> => <font style="color: #000000">#000000</font>
highlight.keyword => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font> => <font style="color: #007700">#007700</font>
highlight.string => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font> => <font style="color: #DD0000">#DD0000</font>
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php => .:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php
input_encoding => no value => no value
internal_encoding => no value => no value
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
mail.add_x_header => On => On
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
mail.log => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_file_uploads => 20 => 20
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_encoding => no value => no value
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 4096K => 4096K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
request_order => GP => GP
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
serialize_precision => 17 => 17
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sys_temp_dir => no value => no value
syslog.facility => LOG_USER => LOG_USER
syslog.filter => no-ctrl => no-ctrl
syslog.ident => php => php
track_errors => Off => Off
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => no value => no value
user_dir => no value => no value
user_ini.cache_ttl => 300 => 300
user_ini.filename => .user.ini => .user.ini
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
zend.assertions => 1 => 1
zend.detect_unicode => On => On
zend.enable_gc => On => On
zend.exception_ignore_args => Off => Off
zend.multibyte => Off => Off
zend.script_encoding => no value => no value
zend.signal_check => Off => Off

ctype

ctype functions => enabled

curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.29.0
Age => 3
Features
AsynchDNS => Yes
CharConv => No
Debug => No
GSS-Negotiate => Yes
IDN => Yes
IPv6 => Yes
krb4 => No
Largefile => Yes
libz => Yes
NTLM => Yes
NTLMWB => Yes
SPNEGO => No
SSL => Yes
SSPI => No
TLS-SRP => No
Protocols => dict, file, ftp, ftps, gopher, http, https, imap, imaps, ldap, ldaps, pop3, pop3s, rtsp, scp, sftp, smtp, smtps, telnet, tftp
Host => x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
SSL Version => NSS/3.44
ZLib Version => 1.2.7
libSSH Version => libssh2/1.8.0

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
curl.cainfo => no value => no value

date

date/time support => enabled
timelib version => 2018.03
"Olson" Timezone Database Version => 0.system
Timezone Database => internal
Default timezone => UTC

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.timezone => no value => no value

dom

DOM/XML => enabled
DOM/XML API Version => 20031129
libxml Version => 2.9.1
HTML Support => enabled
XPath Support => enabled
XPointer Support => enabled
Schema Support => enabled
RelaxNG Support => enabled

exif

EXIF Support => enabled
Supported EXIF Version => 0220
Supported filetypes => JPEG, TIFF
Multibyte decoding support using mbstring => disabled
Extended EXIF tag formats => Canon, Casio, Fujifilm, Nikon, Olympus, Samsung, Panasonic, DJI, Sony, Pentax, Minolta, Sigma, Foveon, Kyocera, Ricoh, AGFA, Epson

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
exif.decode_jis_intel => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_jis_motorola => JIS => JIS
exif.decode_unicode_intel => UCS-2LE => UCS-2LE
exif.decode_unicode_motorola => UCS-2BE => UCS-2BE
exif.encode_jis => no value => no value
exif.encode_unicode => ISO-8859-15 => ISO-8859-15

fileinfo

fileinfo support => enabled
libmagic => 537

filter

Input Validation and Filtering => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
filter.default => unsafe_raw => unsafe_raw
filter.default_flags => no value => no value

ftp

FTP support => enabled
FTPS support => enabled

gettext

GetText Support => enabled

hash

hash support => enabled
Hashing Engines => md2 md4 md5 sha1 sha224 sha256 sha384 sha512/224 sha512/256 sha512 sha3-224 sha3-256 sha3-384 sha3-512 ripemd128 ripemd160 ripemd256 ripemd320 whirlpool tiger128,3 tiger160,3 tiger192,3 tiger128,4 tiger160,4 tiger192,4 snefru snefru256 gost gost-crypto adler32 crc32 crc32b crc32c fnv132 fnv1a32 fnv164 fnv1a64 joaat haval128,3 haval160,3 haval192,3 haval224,3 haval256,3 haval128,4 haval160,4 haval192,4 haval224,4 haval256,4 haval128,5 haval160,5 haval192,5 haval224,5 haval256,5

MHASH support => Enabled
MHASH API Version => Emulated Support

iconv

iconv support => enabled
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.17

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
iconv.input_encoding => no value => no value
iconv.internal_encoding => no value => no value
iconv.output_encoding => no value => no value

json

json support => enabled

libxml

libXML support => active
libXML Compiled Version => 2.9.1
libXML Loaded Version => 20901
libXML streams => enabled

oci8

OCI8 Support => enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support => disabled
OCI8 Version => 2.2.0
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 11.2.0.4.0
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version => 11.2

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
oci8.connection_class => no value => no value
oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100
oci8.events => Off => Off
oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off
oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1
oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60
oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off
oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20

Statistics =>
Active Persistent Connections => 0
Active Connections => 0

openssl

OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
Openssl default config => /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value

pcntl

pcntl support => enabled

pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 10.34 2019-11-21
PCRE Unicode Version => 12.1.0
PCRE JIT Support => enabled
PCRE JIT Target => x86 64bit (little endian + unaligned)

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
pcre.backtrack_limit => 1000000 => 1000000
pcre.jit => 1 => 1
pcre.recursion_limit => 100000 => 100000

Phar

Phar: PHP Archive support => enabled
Phar API version => 1.1.1
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
gzip compression => enabled
bzip2 compression => enabled
Native OpenSSL support => enabled


Phar based on pear/PHP_Archive, original concept by Davey Shafik.
Phar fully realized by Gregory Beaver and Marcus Boerger.
Portions of tar implementation Copyright (c) 2003-2009 Tim Kientzle.
Directive => Local Value => Master Value
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On

posix

POSIX support => enabled

readline

Readline Support => enabled
Readline library => EditLine wrapper

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
cli.pager => no value => no value
cli.prompt => \b \>  => \b \>

Reflection

Reflection => enabled

session

Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user
Registered serializer handlers => php_serialize php php_binary

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => no value => no value
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_samesite => no value => no value
session.cookie_secure => 0 => 0
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 1 => 1
session.lazy_write => On => On
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => no value => no value
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.sid_bits_per_character => 4 => 4
session.sid_length => 32 => 32
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => 1 => 1
session.use_only_cookies => 1 => 1
session.use_strict_mode => 0 => 0
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0

shmop

shmop support => enabled

SimpleXML

SimpleXML support => enabled
Schema support => enabled

sockets

Sockets Support => enabled

sodium

sodium support => enabled
libsodium headers version => 1.0.18
libsodium library version => 1.0.18

SPL

SPL support => enabled
Interfaces => OuterIterator, RecursiveIterator, SeekableIterator, SplObserver, SplSubject
Classes => AppendIterator, ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, BadFunctionCallException, BadMethodCallException, CachingIterator, CallbackFilterIterator, DirectoryIterator, DomainException, EmptyIterator, FilesystemIterator, FilterIterator, GlobIterator, InfiniteIterator, InvalidArgumentException, IteratorIterator, LengthException, LimitIterator, LogicException, MultipleIterator, NoRewindIterator, OutOfBoundsException, OutOfRangeException, OverflowException, ParentIterator, RangeException, RecursiveArrayIterator, RecursiveCachingIterator, RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator, RecursiveDirectoryIterator, RecursiveFilterIterator, RecursiveIteratorIterator, RecursiveRegexIterator, RecursiveTreeIterator, RegexIterator, RuntimeException, SplDoublyLinkedList, SplFileInfo, SplFileObject, SplFixedArray, SplHeap, SplMinHeap, SplMaxHeap, SplObjectStorage, SplPriorityQueue, SplQueue, SplStack, SplTempFileObject, UnderflowException, UnexpectedValueException

standard

Dynamic Library Support => enabled
Path to sendmail => /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
assert.active => 1 => 1
assert.bail => 0 => 0
assert.callback => no value => no value
assert.exception => 0 => 0
assert.quiet_eval => 0 => 0
assert.warning => 1 => 1
auto_detect_line_endings => 0 => 0
default_socket_timeout => 60 => 60
from => no value => no value
session.trans_sid_hosts => no value => no value
session.trans_sid_tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form= => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=
unserialize_max_depth => 4096 => 4096
url_rewriter.hosts => no value => no value
url_rewriter.tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry => a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry
user_agent => no value => no value

sysvmsg

sysvmsg support => enabled

sysvsem

sysvsem support => enabled

sysvshm

sysvshm support => enabled

tokenizer

Tokenizer Support => enabled

xml

XML Support => active
XML Namespace Support => active
libxml2 Version => 2.9.1

xmlreader

XMLReader => enabled

xmlwriter

XMLWriter => enabled

xsl

XSL => enabled
libxslt Version => 1.1.28
libxslt compiled against libxml Version => 2.9.1
EXSLT => enabled
libexslt Version => 1.1.28

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.7
Linked Version => 1.2.7

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => Off => Off
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value

Additional Modules

Module Name

Environment

Variable => Value
XDG_SESSION_ID => 1529
HOSTNAME => rb-opdev-01.mtg.local
SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED =>
SHELL => /bin/bash
TERM => xterm
HISTSIZE => 1000
SSH_CLIENT => 10.105.16.181 53007 22
SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE =>
SSH_TTY => /dev/pts/0
USER => oracle
LD_LIBRARY_PATH => /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
LS_COLORS => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
ORACLE_SID => php1
PATH => /data/oracle/bin:/data/client32/instantclient_19_6:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin
MAIL => /var/spool/mail/oracle
PWD => /usr/include/oracle/11.2/client
LANG => en_US.UTF-8
SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED =>
HISTCONTROL => ignoredups
HOME => /root
SHLVL => 2
LOGNAME => oracle
SSH_CONNECTION => 10.105.16.181 53007 10.10.102.156 22
XDG_DATA_DIRS => /home/oracle/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
LESSOPEN => ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR => /run/user/1001
ORACLE_HOME => /data/oracle
_ => /usr/bin/php
OLDPWD => /usr/include/oracle/11.2

PHP Variables

Variable => Value
$_SERVER['XDG_SESSION_ID'] => 1529
$_SERVER['HOSTNAME'] => rb-opdev-01.mtg.local
$_SERVER['SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED'] =>
$_SERVER['SHELL'] => /bin/bash
$_SERVER['TERM'] => xterm
$_SERVER['HISTSIZE'] => 1000
$_SERVER['SSH_CLIENT'] => 10.105.16.181 53007 22
$_SERVER['SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE'] =>
$_SERVER['SSH_TTY'] => /dev/pts/0
$_SERVER['USER'] => oracle
$_SERVER['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] => /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
$_SERVER['LS_COLORS'] => rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:
$_SERVER['ORACLE_SID'] => php1
$_SERVER['PATH'] => /data/oracle/bin:/data/client32/instantclient_19_6:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/oracle/.local/bin:/home/oracle/bin
$_SERVER['MAIL'] => /var/spool/mail/oracle
$_SERVER['PWD'] => /usr/include/oracle/11.2/client
$_SERVER['LANG'] => en_US.UTF-8
$_SERVER['SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED'] =>
$_SERVER['HISTCONTROL'] => ignoredups
$_SERVER['HOME'] => /root
$_SERVER['SHLVL'] => 2
$_SERVER['LOGNAME'] => oracle
$_SERVER['SSH_CONNECTION'] => 10.105.16.181 53007 10.10.102.156 22
$_SERVER['XDG_DATA_DIRS'] => /home/oracle/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
$_SERVER['LESSOPEN'] => ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
$_SERVER['XDG_RUNTIME_DIR'] => /run/user/1001
$_SERVER['ORACLE_HOME'] => /data/oracle
$_SERVER['_'] => /usr/bin/php
$_SERVER['OLDPWD'] => /usr/include/oracle/11.2
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] =>
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] =>
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] =>
$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED'] =>
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] =>
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] => 1595485171.3729
$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] => 1595485171
$_SERVER['argv'] => Array
(
)

$_SERVER['argc'] => 0

PHP License
This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the PHP License as published by the PHP Group
and included in the distribution in the file:  LICENSE

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

If you did not receive a copy of the PHP license, or have any
questions about PHP licensing, please contact license@php.net.
[root@rb-opdev-01 client]#
```

Comment: [root@rb-opdev-01 logs]# which php
/usr/bin/php

Oracle Home (basic and client 11.2.0.4)
./include/oracle/11.2/client64

Comment: Whatever OCI is: if it is not listed in phpinfo or it's equivalents, its not installed properly.

Comment: The multiple times i've had to deal with this error it's always because the oci version i installed doesn't match the one required by the php version.

Comment: `/opt/lampp/htdocs` suggests a web server but you run your checks from command-line. They're different interpreters with different settings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the **php-oci8** package which provides the needed extensions (oci8 and pdo_oci).

You also need the latest Oracle Client library version 19.x

See: [Installation of Oracle extensions for PHP](https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2020/05/18/Installation-of-Oracle-extensions-for-PHP)

Comment: should i remove the oracle-instantclient11.2-basic-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm and oracle-instantclient11.2-devel-11.2.0.4.0-1.x86_64.rpm?

Comment: Hi,

still same issue after following steps in the doc

Comment: [root@rb-opdev-01 oracle]# php --ri oci8

oci8

OCI8 Support => enabled
OCI8 DTrace Support => enabled
OCI8 Version => 2.2.0
Oracle Run-time Client Library Version => 19.8.0.0.0
Oracle Compile-time Instant Client Version => 19.6

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
oci8.max_persistent => -1 => -1
oci8.persistent_timeout => -1 => -1
oci8.ping_interval => 60 => 60
oci8.privileged_connect => Off => Off
oci8.statement_cache_size => 20 => 20
oci8.default_prefetch => 100 => 100
oci8.old_oci_close_semantics => Off => Off

Comment: So, according to your comment, it works.
Perhaps you forget to restart the web server and / or FPM service

Comment: I restarted lampp and even rebooted the server. Still I cannot find the OCI8 entry loaded in phpinfo. Pls advise.

Comment: Sorry, probably not enough information, but if it works from command lilne, I don't see any reason why it doesn't in web.

Comment: Based on the original post: Since you have Instant Client, you should NOT have ORACLE_HOME set.  E.g. work out want is setting this`ORACLE_HOME => /data/oracle`.  Assuming you have now installed Instant Client 19.8 RPMs, check that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is unset (since Instant Client 19 RPMs already run ldconfig).  Again, your original post shows this was set to the 11.2 path.